# Windows 8 XAML AppBar Icon Not Showing

Tags: xaml, windows-8

Well, after it initially not working I managed to find the `StandardStyles.xaml` file which contains things like `{StaticResource EditAppBarButtonStyle}` that are used all over MSDN in examples. I uncommented the declaration of `EditAppBarButtonStyle` in `StandardStyles.xaml` so now the app does not crash but now it just shows up with this:

[image]

And the XAML code is:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="bottomAppBar" Padding="10,0,10,0" Background="Black">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button x:Name="Edit" Tag="Edit" Content="{StaticResource EditAppBarButtonStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

After searching all over I can't figure this one out. I didn't even see StandardStyles.xaml mention anywhere, I had to download a sample from MSDN and then go through every file and see what was different. Could anybody tell me why it does not show up with an icon? It is probably a quick thing that I just haven't managed to find.

Also, is this sort of stuff actually mentioned anywhere on MSDN? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you set the style to the `Content` property rather than the `Style` property.

Try:

```
<Button x:Name="Edit" Tag="Edit" Width="115" Height="70" Style="{StaticResource EditAppBarButtonStyle}"/>
```

In xaml, if you set an object to display that isn't a visual object, then it will simply print the type of the object, which is why you saw `Windows.UI.Xaml.Style` since that is the type of a style.

Comment: Thanks for this. A related question, I now have the correct Icon, do you know how to change what text is shown underneath it?

Comment: Nevermind, found it myself... `AutomationProperties.Name="Custom text"`